# SSRS stored procedure dataset miss some values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services, dataset

When I execute the dataset from SSRS some cells stay blank compare to the SQL management studio set of results. I didn't find any help in case when only some results are missing.

[image: See SSRS vs SQL Studio results]

Comment: Share your queries, it might be something with formatting. just from what information you provided its hard to understand the issue

Comment: Hi Deepak, finally I just found the issue when reviewing before posting my sp on line. At the end of the SP I have an if for executing 2 different select base on one condition. Unfortunatly I let one column more on one of the select for debug purpose which give me two different table size in return. I'm surprised that not cause any errors when executed. Thanks